# Can I define a javascript variable that uses onsubmit in a form defining that form as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If i use an "onsubmit" attribute in a form to run an Javascript function, is there a way to define that specific form in the function? For example if I have this form:

```
<form onsubmit="return submit()" name="FormA" class="foo">
    <input type="submit" value=""Submit">
</form>
```

Can I define a variable in the the function that would be the same as

```
var x = document.forms["FormA"]
```

but using some method to recognize that the submitting form is form that should be defined?

Comment: Yes, just pass `this` to the `onsubmit` function: `onsubmit="return submit(this)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` in your function call to pass the form to it.

```js
function submit(form) {
  console.log(form);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submit(this);" name="FormA" class="foo">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```